# using streamReader class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

```
  public class myRows
   {
       public decimal Number1 { get; set; }
       public decimal Number2 { get; set; }
       public decimal Number3 { get; set; }
       public decimal Number4 { get; set; }
       public decimal Number5 { get; set; }
       public decimal Number6 { get; set; }
       public string Date1 { get; set; }

       public myRows(string str)
       {
               Number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(str.Substring(3, 7));
               Number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(str.Substring(15, 8));
               Number3 = Convert.ToDecimal(str.Substring(24, 8));
               Number4 = Convert.ToDecimal(str.Substring(36, 8));
               Number5 = Convert.ToDecimal(str.Substring(47, 8));
               Number6 = Convert.ToDecimal(str.Substring(58, 8));
               Date1 = str.Substring(65, 25);
       }
   }
```

i then read the text file data like

```
var myRows = new List<myRows>();
var myR = new StreamReader(txtFileToImport.Text);
while (!myR.EndOfStream)
      {
          string s = myR.ReadLine();
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()))
          {
             myRows.Add(new myRows(s));
          }
          }
  myR.Close();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = myRows;
```

The problem am having is pre-determining the startIndex and length of the white space between the column values in the text file e.g here `Convert.ToDecimal(str.Substring(3, 7));`

White space between column values isn't uniform, it can be 5 between column 1 and 2 and then be 8 between column 7 and 8.

Currently, i have to know in advance the index at which the white space starts and ends. Is there away i can dynamically get the start Index of the white space and its length with out getting to look at the text file to be processed?

What i really need is the parameters passed to `str.Substring(,)` not to be hard corded.

@Habib: **sample text file is here**
[image]

Comment: was about to say split... +1

Comment: @SQL.Net Warrior, can you put a sample input string, ?

Comment: @Habib, i have added a sample text file screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) on the space character with the [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) option.  This will remove the empty fields effectively leaving only fields with your data.

Given a line of your text file in `line`, your code would look something like this:

```
var fields = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var Number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[0]);
var Number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[1]);
// etc.
```

Since your date data is broken up into several descrete fields (day of week, month, day, etc) you'll 'reassemble' them through the fields they'll occupy and assign to your `Date1`:

```
var Date1 = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", fields[7], fields[8], fields[9], fields[10], fields[11]);
```

Of course in production code you'll want to validate a couple things:

- You've read the expected number of fields
- That you can safely convert your string field values to Doubles (for this
  use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx))

Comment: If you cab be of help, i have posted a followup/related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741302/using-streamreader-class-to-read-text-file-with-dynamic-number-of-columns-in-c-s

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.Split(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)) on your `string` and later use the array index rather than string positions to convert the numbers. Splitting the string on white space will remove the white space from the string. Something like:

```
public myRows(string str)
       {
          string[] splitArray = str.Split(); //split on white space
          if(splitArray.Length > 7)
              {
               Number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(splitArray[0]);
               //,....... So on
              }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

using `Split` method split your line into 8 parts. Last one will be your date.

```
var parts = line.Split(new char[]{' '}, 8, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Number1 = Decimal.Parse(parts[0]);
Number2 = Decimal.Parse(parts[1]);
......
......
DateTime Date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(parts[7],"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```